# Regular expression issue in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My string will be like following

```
'popular-game-show-identifier-popular-games-mv-11'
```

In above string I want to check,

1. Each word must followed by hyphen, except first word.
2. In between the string `identifier` word must exist.
3. End of the string must contain `-mv-` appended to digit.

To check 1, 3 following regular expression working fine.

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(-mv-(\d+))$/
```

Now I want to check 2 also, for that I'm modified above expression to

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\-identifier\-)(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(-mv-(\d+))$/
```

`preg_match()` always returning `0` if I use above regular expression to check all 3 conditions. I'm not getting where I've did wrong.

Comment: _Each word must followed by hyphen, expect **first** word._; I think you mean _except **last** word_.

Comment: Ya, corrected spelling.

Comment: why not use explode('-', $myString) and then do all the necessary checking?

Comment: @jeff: As of my requirement I can't use that, I want to check all those conditions with regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "extra" hyphen

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\-identifier\-)(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(-mv-(\d+))$/
```

Should be

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\-identifier)(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(-mv-(\d+))$/
```

Comment: FYI - hyphens aren't special unless used in a range in a character class. They do not need to be escaped